# How to prove a function is constant, satisfying certain properties?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, continuity

Suppose I had a function like $f:(-1, 1) \rightarrow \mathbb R$ that satisfied $f(x) = f(x^2)$ for all x \in (-1, 1). If $f$ is continuous at x = 0, then I want to show that $f$ is a constant. However, I am really not sure what to do here. I thought about using the fact that $f(x) = f(x^{1/2}) = ... = f(x^{1/{2^n}})$ for all $0 \lt x$. I know that in this case, the limit as n approaches infinity of $f(x^{1/{2^n}})$ will be equal to f(1). But I'm not sure how I can equate this to f(x) itself, and use the fact that $f$ is continuous at 0. Also, if x \lt 0, then you cannot take square roots of negative numbers, so I'm not sure what would come next. I'm quite stuck on this, so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$|f(x)-f(0)|=|f(x^{2})-f(0)|=|f(x^{4})-f(0)|$ and hence $|f(x)-f(0)|=|f(x^{2^n})-f(0)|$. But $x^{2^n}\rightarrow 0$ for $x\in(-1,1)$ and $n\rightarrow\infty$. As $f$ is continuous at $0$, so $|f(u)-f(0)|<\epsilon$ whenever $|u|<\delta$, now put $n$ large enough to let $u=x^{2^n}$.

You end up with $|f(x)-f(0)|<\epsilon$ but $\epsilon>0$ is arbitrary, so $f(x)=f(0)$.

**A Cheating Argument:**

\begin{align*}
f(x)&=f(x^{2^{n}})\\
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}f(x)&=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}f(x^{2^{n}})\\
f(x)&=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}f(x^{2^{n}}).
\end{align*}
Now $\lim_{u\rightarrow 0}f(u)=f(0)$ and $x^{2^{n}}\rightarrow 0$, let $u=x^{2^{n}}$ we get $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}f(x^{2^{n}})=f(0)$ and hence $f(x)=f(0)$.

Comment: Thanks for all this. I understand most of it, but I didn't get why you let u be equal to $x^{2n}$. I thought that the value of u had to be within $\delta$.

Comment: That's the reason I stressed that one needs to pick $n$ large enough to get $x^{2^{n}}$ small enough to insert within $\delta$.

Comment: It makes sense now. Thanks.

Comment: But isn't it okay to say that if $f (x)=f (1)$ then $f (0)=f (1)=f (x) $? You can assume $x\in (-1,1) $, no need to exclude the zero I guess.

Comment: $f(1)$ is not defined as the domain doesn't include the point $1$.

Comment: Of course that's not a real concern, even if $1$ is included in the domain, how does it follow that $f(x)=f(1)$? $f$ need no to be continuous at $1$, so the OP trick doesn't work.

Comment: $f(x) = f(x^{1/2}) = ... = f(x^{1/{2^n}})$ you let $n$ go to infinity.

Comment: Yes, but then even that $x^{1/2^{n}}$ converges to $1$, $f(x^{1/2^{n}})$ need no converge to $f(1)$, this will happen when $f$ is continuous at $1$, but it is not told if this is the case.

Comment: i understand that :) i don't get what you mean by "need no", now?

Comment: I was saying that, $x^{1/{2^{n}}}\rightarrow 1$ but it is not necessary that case that $f(x^{1/2^{n}})\rightarrow f(1)$.